# How to make tmux.conf to name windows based on their window index only and not display the hostname

Tags: tmux

How to make tmux.conf to name windows based on their window index only and not display the hostname after it. It should just display the window index only.
Currently tmux by default is showing the user hostname as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
set -g window-status-current-style "#I"
set -g window-status-style "#I"
```